# Prove/disprove statements regarding continuous functions.

Tags: functions, continuity

I found some old math tests from my school years and thought it might be fun to see what I still remember. The answer is simply, not as much as I hoped for. I'm having trouble proving/disproving these statements, not sure where to go with it.

1. If f is a continuous function on the closed interval [a,b] then f([a,b] = [f(a),f(b)] or f([a,b]) = [f(b),f(a)].
2. There exists a function f that maps ]0,1[ to R/Z+
3. Is there a continuous function that maps ]0,10] to R?

I'm pretty sure that when I get 2, 3 will follow closely, hopefully at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

- Consider $f(x) = \sin{x}$ on $[0, \pi]$.
- A continuous image of a connected set must be connected.
- Consider an oscillating function that "blows up" at $0$; something like $\frac{1}{x^2} \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ might be relevant to you.

Comment: This is why I've always loved math. You have no idea what you're looking at, then someone just slightly gives you a push and suddenly you're in the light and everything is clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Zanii Glad I could help :)